# D3 scale how to put only the minimum and the max number on the scale

Tags: d3.js, d3plus

Creating the scale:

```
headers.forEach(function(d) {
            // Coerce values to numbers.
            jsonObj.forEach(function(p) {
                y[d] = d3.scale.linear().domain(
                        d3.extent(jsonObj, function(p) {
                            return +p[d] || 0;
                        })).range([ h, 0 ]);
                y[d].brush = d3.svg.brush().y(y[d]).on("brush", brush);
            });
        }); 



g.append("svg:g").attr("class", "axis").each(function(d) {
            d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d]));
```

the Scale is comming [0.0,0.1,0.2,...,1.0]

I want something like this [0,1].

It's possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into `axis.ticks()`. I assume `axis.ticks(2)` would give you just the min and max axis values.

Another option that would probably work if you know the min/max values in advance, or want to calculate them, is `axis.ticksValues()`.

More info on both, plus lots of other details about the axis, can be found at https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#ticks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the `.ticks()` method of the axis, which specifies the number of ticks on the axis.

Try: `d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d]).ticks(2));`